# Replace x axis values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Let's say I have this code :

```
nbrs = np.array([0, 13, 13, 7, -9, 0])
x_values = np.array([0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250])
plt.plot(nbrs)
plt.xticks(my_xticks)
```

[image]

When I tried `xticks` it doesn't work :

```
nbrs = np.array([0, 13, 13, 7, -9, 0])
x_values = np.array([0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250])
plt.plot(nbrs)
plt.xticks(my_xticks)
```

[image]

Instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` I want to have `[0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply:

```
plt.plot(x_values,nbrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your x-values to the `plt.plot` function. No need to use `plt.xticks`. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nbrs = np.array([0, 13, 13, 7, -9, 0])
x_values = np.array([0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250])
plt.plot(x_values,nbrs)
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/powpp.png)